# Spinor representation

Tags: group-theory, group-representations, spinors

I am trying to study Special unitary group of order 2 and some textbooks mention objects transform under special unitary group are called [Spinors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor). then How can we represent a spinor using matrix?

Comment: Linear representations in general are homomorphisms of a Lie-group to the space of matrices which by acting on a particular vector space (there where the actual spinor "lives") maintain the vector space invariant, i.e. it is a tuple (matrix, vector space). (this is obviously not a mathematically rigorous explanation). A more detailed explanation of the particular spinor representation is out of scope of SE. Consult wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest kind of spinors can be thought of as column vectors with two entries. Each group element of $SU(2)$ can be represented as a $2\times 2$ matrix which acts on a spinor to produce another spinor.

This is similar to how $3\times 3$ rotation matrices act on $3$-vectors to rotate them.

It is important to be clear on the distinction between the things being transformed and the transformations being performed on them.

The Pauli matrices can be used to construct the entire $2\times 2$ representation of $SU(2)$ through matrix exponentiation, because they generate the infinitesimal group transformations.

By the way, the *order* of a group is the number of group elements. For $SU(2)$, this is infinite, not two. For $SU(n)$, $n$ is called the *degree*.